# How to check the status of an SSAS cube while it is processing

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

When one processes an analysis services cube in Sql Server Management Studio, by right clicking on the cube name in the GUI and selecting the "process" option, a GUI pops up and displays the status of the cube partitions and amount of time that the cube processing has been running for each partition.

I am working on a system which remotely processes analysis services cubes. It does this by sending an XMLA script telling the server to process the cube to the ASCMD executable.

As far as I can tell the only output from ASCMD is just trace/warning/error gibberish, and does not output information that would be easily useful without some complex parsing.

Is there any way to check the processing status of a cube, while it is processing, to gather information such as which partitions are currently being processed and the time they started, etc...?

Using ascmd isn't a strict requirement, if there are other microsoft executable which are used behind the scenes to process cubes I can switch, it is just important I gather a semi-real-time status of the current cube that is processing.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899250/how-to-determine-which-ssas-cube-is-processing-now and additional DMVs for SSAS stats here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx

Comment: @Dave I am fairly new to cubes and SSAS development, do you know which of these Dynamic Management Rowsets would inform me of which elements of the cube have been processed?